# Preventing page lifecycle for one control

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I'm using a file manager-type `WebControl` that does lots of postbacks.  It's placed inside a `Page` that is relatively complex.  I would like to prevent the `WebControl` from causing the whole `Page` to go through the lifecycle.  An `UpdatePanel` helps a little, but not enough.

Is there any way to isolate the `WebControl` from the rest of the `Page`?  The only way I can think of is sticking the `WebControl` in a separate `Page` and creating an `iframe` in the original `Page`.  Unfortunately that also means my `WebControl` properties/settings are no longer in the original `Page`.  If I want two instances of the `WebControl` with different settings, then I have to create a `Page` for each setting and reference the correct one in my `iframes`.  Not quite as "drag & drop" as I would like.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, you can't prevent a control from going through lifecycle; is there anyway to identify though, that during a certain page postback, you prevent the code from running in each event handler by doing something like:

```
if (_shouldNotRun == true)
   return;

//Event handler code
```

Essentially, figuring out some way to indicate whether the control should run may be an option.  IFrame would work, but yes you have to deal with the issues you mentioned.  Can you give more detals to the problem?

HTH.

Comment: It's the other way around.  I would need a way to indicate whether the rest of the page should run.  This is a file manager, so simply creating a folder, renaming, etc. has to post back.  I don't want the rest of the page slowing down a simple folder change.  Unfortunately some things can't be prevented such as creating the control tree...

Comment: No, if you tried to change the control tree, you would get an error.  You could use a hidden field written by javascript to say this action happened on the client, when the server posts back, you can then check the hidden field (either the control or a client-hidden field through the form collection) to see if you should allow the rest of the page to load.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what events possible to override that are called on PostBack. A good source for the Life Cycle of a page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

But it sounds as it would be better to remake your control to create Ajax webservice requests for the functions that are possible to prevent most of the postback's?

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Using a web service would be ideal, unfortunately it's not my control and it's relatively complex...  I'll see if I can find any alternative & easy ways to solve this...